# socket.io / multiples canales en angular

Tags: angular, socket.io, servicio

intento hacer una conexion con un socket en angular para mostrar una barra de progreso, el socket maneja 2 canales :

Hay dos canales 
•   bar
•   progress

bar: puede recibir dos valores: “show” (muestra la barra)y “hide”(oculta la barra)
progress: solo devuelve un objeto json con los datos de quien envía, total y actual

aqui muestro mi servicio de la conexion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien podria ayudarme como manipular y acceder a canales ?